# intersection of 100*100 elements and any suggestion for a better data structure?

Tags: python, dictionary, bigdata

okay heres the problem!
i have created a dictionary something like this

```
a={'t1':[{seta1},{seta2},{seta3},{seta4}],
   't2':[{setb1},{setb2},{setb3},{setb4}],
    .
    .
    .
   't100':[{setz1},{setz2},{setz3},{setz4}]}
```

where 't1','t2',....,'t100' are the timestamps and {set1},{set2},{set3},{set4} are the disjoint sets of clusters at those respective timestamps.

now i want to find intersections of each and every set set with every other set across timestamps.
i.e., assuming

```
b={}   # is my resulting dictionary
```

Initially b is empty so 'b' contains entire a['t1'] with key 't1'

```
b['t1']=a['t1'] #isn't this a deep copy? cos i replicating the values. Is there a way to achieve a shallow copy? thought of using .copy() and .update() method but couldn't figure out any possible way.
```

as the iterations goes on, I find the intersections and update the resulting dictionary as follows.

```
k=[i&j for i in a[key1] for j in b[key2]]

#if intersections between a and b are empty sets, then i will create 'key1' in b and put the corresponding value of key1 in b
#if key1 is already present in b, then i will append the a[key1] value into b[key1] and remove the corresponding value from a[key1]

#if the intersections are found, and the length of each intersection is >2, i will do something like this
b[key2+','+key1] not in b.keys(): 
  b[key2+','+key1]=[] #b[t1,t2]=non-empty intersections whose length is >2
b[key2+','+key1]=k #where k holds the intersection and the empty sets and intersections with length one are removed before this stage
```

suppose that i have each seta1, seta2, seta3 etc.,. having 100 elements each
then isn't finding intersections very intensive? (100*100) is there any efficient way to find intersections easily? How to cut down the intensity? I believe I read somewhere that worst case scenario of intersection is

```
     O(len(s)*len(t))
```

to sum it up:

- to find intersection in an easier way? is numpy's intersect1d better than this?
- is there possibly a better data structure for computation? (i thought heap would be the choice, but again after every insertion the heap tree should be rearranged to attain "parental dominance property". any other suggestion?)
- to achieve a shallow copy of a particular key-value pair from one dictionary to another.

any help would be very much appreciated.! :)
thanks in adv.! :) :)

Comment: could you post a small example? I don't understand what "find intersections of each and every set set with every other set across timestamps" means

Comment: @zodiac i have posted the example here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596432/intersect-multiple-sets-in-a-dictionary-python
pls have a look

Comment: both I and at least one other commenter find the example unhelpful. why does 't1,t2,t3' contain, for example, 4 and 5 but not 1?

Comment: @zodiac 't1', 't2' ,'t3' etc are the various timestamps. the values associated with with each timestamps are the clusters. I am trying to find intersection of these clusters i.e., for example (each_cluster_in_t1)intersection(each_cluster_in_t2) becomes value to another key 't1,t2'suppose if 
      't1':[{4,5},{6,7,8},{1}]
      't2':[{4,5,6},{7,8},{1,2}]
 then 't1,t2' would contain [{4,5},{7,8}] #{1} ignored 
     if 't3':[{4,5,6,7},{8},{1,2}]
  then 't1,t2,t3' would be 't1,t2' intersection 't3'
      => 't1,t2,t3':[{4,5}] #correspondingly {4,5} popped off from 't1,t2' as it is in 't1,t2,t3'

Comment: why doesn't the output in your example contain the keys 't3,t4' and 't4'? why is {1} ignored?

Comment: i am trying to find swarms using these clusters. any object set of length 1 (as in the case of {1}) cannot become a swarm so it is being ignored. 
and now that you have asked that 't3,t4' is not included, I am wondering if my code is wrong. The question is very much valid and 
i want to have 't3,t4' in my resultant dictionary with values {5,6,7} and {1,2} so probably i need to redo the code :(